# window.open needs enter key to be pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using window.open("http://localhost:8080/testurl/users.jsp?idUser=2");

When i run the code, new window is opened with the above url but empty page is displayed. I need to press enter again then only above page is being displayed. Can someone let me know what is the issue. Second thing is need to disable the url once window is opened as there is a chance of editing the id.

Comment: How do you call window.open function, with a click?

Comment: @Nestoraj, Yes on click of a button.

Comment: are you using "onclick" event? if not it could be the problem

Comment: If you provided more code it would eliminate some confusion and allow others to help you.